# Number of truth outputs of a Boolean function

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, boolean-ring

> **Disjunctive Normal Form (DNF)** A Boolean function $f$ of $n$ variables is said to be in a  DNF if it is a disjunction of conjunction in $n$ variables. That is, each conjunction includes all the variables of the formula and there are no duplicates.  We can build a  DNF by looking at a truth table and matching a unique conjunction to each of the truth outputs.

Let $f=\overline{AB}CD+\bar{A}BCD+ABCD+A\bar{B}C\bar{D}$, then its DNF is
$
f=\overline{AB}CD+\bar{A}BCD+ABCD+A\bar{B}C\bar{D}$

$=(\bar{A}+\bar{B})CD+\bar{A}BCD+ABCD+A\bar{B}C\bar{D}$

$=\bar{A}CD(B+\bar{B})+\bar{B}CD(A+\bar{A})+\bar{A}BCD+ABCD+A\bar{B}C\bar{D}$

$=ABCD+\bar{A}BCD+\bar{A}\bar{B}CD+A\bar{B}CD+A\bar{B}C\bar{D}.$

In view of definition of DNF, the number of truth outputs of $f$ must be equal to the number of terms in DNF of $f$. Therefore, the number of truth outputs in this case must be $5$. But I found in an article that the number of truth outputs is $4$, and in that article the combination of the value $A\overline{B}CD$ is missing from the list of combinations leading to a truth output.

I need a confirmation, whether the number of truth outputs of $f$ is $4$ or $5$?

**Edited:**

This is online generated truth table for the first expression.

[image]

Hence it is verified that the number of truth outputs is $5$, but not $4$.

Comment: That first expression (with 4 terms) is already in DNF ... so how are you getting that second expression?  That second expression is the first disjuncted with $A\overline{B}CD$, and indeed when $A$, $C$, and $D$ are all true, ad=nd $B$ is false, then the second expression evaluates to True, but the first to false, so they are not equivalent.

Comment: @Bram28 No. First expression is not in DNF form due to $\overline{AB}$. Expanding it using De Morgan's law, what do we get?

Comment: @Bram28 please check the proof in the question.

Comment: But your final expression also has $\overline{AB}$.

Comment: And isn't @Bram correct in stating that $f$ is false if $A,C,D$ are true with $B$ false, but your proposed DNF is true in that case, so they can't be equivalent?

Comment: @GerryMyerson The last line hasn't $\overline{AB}$, but the third term of the last line is $\ overline{A}\overline{B}$. Regarding equivalence, I am bit confused. Because we normally construct DNF from its truth table. Using truth table is useful for determining both DNF and CNF.

Comment: The statement of @Bram is not true because the notation $\overline{AB}CD$ is nothing but $(AB)^cCD$. So, when $A$ is true and $B$ is false, $(AB)$ must be false, whose complement is true.

Comment: @gete  Sorry, I read $\overline{AB}$ as $\overline{A}\overline{B}$ instead of $\overline{AB}$ ... and that's exactly why I fervently hate that notation :P

Comment: @Bram28 Yes the notation is really confusing..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had do edit your question to understand what was going on. Right from the start, there is a MathJax problem: the commands '\overline{AB}' and '\overline{A}\overline{B}' produce
$\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{A}\overline{B}$, respectively, so the output is the same on the screen. One solution could be to use '\bar{A}\bar{B}' in the latter case, which produces the output ${\bar A}{\bar B}$.

Thus your final line should be
$$ABCD+\overline{A}BCD+\bar{A}\bar{B}CD+A\overline{B}CD+A\overline{B}C\overline{D}$$
which is now the right DNF.

Comment: So, do you say that the number of truth outputs should be $5$?

Comment: It looks like you verified yourself that 5 is the number of truth outputs.